# Which Assembly contains LINQ extension method Delete?

Tags: linq, crm, linqpad

I am trying to delete a row from an entity named xyz in CRM using the following code in LINQPAD

```
    var d = from z in xyz
where z.exch_ZipCode == "60069" 
&& z.exch_zipcodeId.Value== new Guid("c6e88a07-b4a2-e211-b8d2-bc305befb465")
select new
{
zipId = z.exch_zipcodeId.Value,
zip = z.exch_ZipCode,
};
d.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(row=>row.Delete());
```

I have added System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll but I get the following error

'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'Delete' and no extension method 'Delete' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

Comment: _What_ is `xyz`? If it's a `DataTable` (as suggested by `DataSetExtensions`) and you want to delete every row in the query include it as property in your anonymous type.

Comment: There is no LINQ `Delete` method.

Comment: I need to delete one row from the CRM entity named xyz using LINQ. This row is selected by the where clause in the above statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is LinqToSql then to delete rows you use [DeleteOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [DeleteAllOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For example, if you want to delete all rows in xyz matching your criteria, you can do something like :

```
var query = (from z in xyz
    where z.exch_ZipCode == "60069" 
       && z.exch_zipcodeId.Value== new Guid("c6e88a07-b4a2-e211-b8d2-bc305befb465")
    select z);

xyz.DeleteAllOnSumit(query);
SubmitChanges();
```